# Vim with Pyflakes "Caught deadly signal SEGV."

Tags: vim, pyflakes

More frequent than I would like my vim crashes with the terminal prompting Vim:

> Caught deadly signal SEGV.

I use vim with the pyflakes plugin to edit python scripts.

#### Does anyone know what this problem could be caused by?

I run Mac OSX 10.10.

Comment: Segmentation faults are bugs in vim. Please report to vim-dev (Read `:h bug-reports`)

Comment: @FDinoff Except this is probably a packaging SNAFU that has to do with mismatching versions of Python, rather than with Vim.

Comment: So where would I best turn to?

Comment: The place you got Vim from should have some kind of support forum.  Posting there might be a good start.

Comment: @lcd047 But my Vim is the standard one provided from factory start by the Mac...

Comment: @Jack I'm not sure I understand your point.  Does the fact that you use the default Vim that came with your Mac prevent you from asking on their forums about using it together with pylint?

Comment: @lcd047 Ok I see what you mean - ill turn towards the mac forums.